# Running IIS Application with different user Credentials

Tags: security, iis

I have deployed an application on IIS Server and Servlet Exec configured. I need run the application with windows User Credentials rather than Anonymous User. I tries changing the username and password of annonmous user in properties/Security but the application stops responding changing it back to default Anonymous IIS user account works fine??

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the version of IIS you are using but I believe if you set/change the identity of the application pool for your website this would do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running an ASP.NET application, you may try enabling impersonation in the web.config. See MSDN for further information on impersonation

Comment: I am using Servlet Exec configured with IIS not ASP.net

Answer (score 0):

Does it prompt for a username\password?  If so, make sure to give the user at least read permissions on disk to the site path.  It should have read permissions.  If not, can you explain what you mean by 'stops responding'?